# How can I generate temporary URL in play framework?

Tags: playframework, change-password

I am using play framework and Java to build an web application. I have a reset password feature in my application. I do not want to generate temporary passwords and email them to the users. Instead, I want to generate temporary URL that is valid for x days and email it to the user where he/she an use it to reset his/her password. I am not sure how I can implement that in Play Framework, or even if it is possible in Play.

**[Update]**
I want to know how to add the temporary URL to my application routes file. I am not even sure if this the right place add the temporary URL. How to generate the link, I believe I know how to implement that, but how to add it to my application, I am not sure if my question is clear enough, sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, add two fields stored in DB to your User model: `String token` and `Date tokenValidityDate`.

When user requests password change set new `token` to database which is perfectly unique ie. `123,6svv376d.foo.bar.loooong.hash` where `123` is ID of user and rest after comma is random hash calculated with application secret. in `tokenValidityDate` field add the final date when token is valid let's say **now** + 1 hour.

then generate an absolute link i.e.:

`http://domain.com/password-reset/123,6svv376d.foo.bar.loooong.hash` to send in email.

Ater receiving such request you can:

- if user with given token found and his/her `tokenValidityDate` isn't less the now -> display form for setting new pass and process as usually.
- if user with given token found, but it's too late, redirect to common form with "Remind the password" + flash message: `Your token expired, start again`, also set `token` and `tokenValidityDate` for this user to null.
- if user with given token is NOT found, redirect to common form with "Remind the password" without any message.